# Firebase removeValue() function not removing the right value

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm working on adding a edit and delete function to my app. The edit function works fine, but my delete function does not always delete the right value.

Scenarios when the delete function does not work as intended:

- When I add a new data node (new Supplier in my app's case.)
- When I edit a value, the last edited value is deleted instead of the one selected.
- When starting the app, deleting just one of the items deletes the entirety of "SUPPLIERS".
- Having to click the delete button twice to delete an item.

---

This is the structure of my databse :

SUPPLIERS >>>

=============> auto - generated key (ex. -LpmoJ8DjCvF23I2ymVg)

=======================================================> Supplier_Name

=======================================================> Supplier_Address

=======================================================> Supplier_PhoneNum

=======================================================> Supplier_Email

---

Here is my delete function, it is an onClickListener, and uses AlertDialog for confirmation:

```
btnMenuDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SupplierMaintenance.this);
                builder.setTitle("DELETE Supplier");
                builder.setMessage("You are about to delete the selected supplier. Continue?");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        //DELETE METHOD
                        databaseSupp = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("SUPPLIERS");
                        final DatabaseReference mDatabase2 = databaseSupp;

                        mDatabase2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {

                                for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot2.getChildren()) {
                                    if (snapshot.child("Supplier_Name").getValue(String.class).equals(suppName.getText().toString())) {
                                        deletekey = snapshot.getKey().toString();
                                        keyholder.setText(deletekey);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                        mDatabase2.child(keyholder.getText().toString()).removeValue();
                    }
                });

                builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                //DELETE METHOD END
            }
        });
```

In order to delete a value, I get the item's auto generated key, and use that as reference to delete that key's entire node. This works fine in my edit function, but not in my delete function.

I think it has to do something with the onDataChange, but I am not sure.

**Note**: The items are in a **recyclerView**, and the user is allowed to edit or delete them if they wish to at any time.

I have tried moving the onDatachange method, moving the removeValue() function to different places, and setting the key in a TextView before using it to make sure it is the right key, which it is, but for some reason it does not work as intended, deleting other items which weren't chosen.

I have been stuck on this problem for 3 days, as I am a beginner to this kind of programming, and this is my first full-on app.

If you need anymore code I can post as much as needed.

Any help is greatly appreciated :).

Comment: I've been trying everything that I know, but my knowledge on Firebase is limited, and this has been bugging me for so long :(

Comment: do you want to delete the node who values is changed and also the supplier_name is as provided is the input of suppName

Comment: Once the user clicks on "delete" on an item in the recyclerView, the clicked item should be deleted, including its auto-generated key, and everything underneath that key, but nothing else except the chosen item

Comment: What's happening is that sometimes a different key and its contents is deleted, even when it isn't selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the code, try the grasp the logic . Any doubt is welcomed

```
btnMenuDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SupplierMaintenance.this);
            builder.setTitle("DELETE Supplier");
            builder.setMessage("You are about to delete the selected supplier. Continue?");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //DELETE METHOD
                    databaseSupp = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("SUPPLIERS");
                    final DatabaseReference mDatabase2 = databaseSupp;

                    mDatabase2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {

                            for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot2.getChildren()) {
                                if (snapshot.child("Supplier_Name").getValue(String.class).equals(suppName.getText().toString())) {
                                    deletekey = snapshot.getKey().toString();
                                    keyholder.setText(deletekey);
               mDatabase2.child(keyholder.getText().toString()).removeValue();  
                                     return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            builder.show();
            //DELETE METHOD END
        }
    });
```

I hope the supplier_name are unique

Comment: I tested all the scenarios that were possible to happen, and all the scenarios that made the delete function act weird, but it always deletes the right one now. Amazing!

Comment: First of all you should remember that you all the listener are asynchrous call. please   read more on google. Also  I don't why you were using valueEventListener since it will keep on listening the change is given ref  and you don't need to

Comment: Yeah I'm going to read up more on Firebase functions and their differences. I'll replace the valueEventListener for something more appropriate to the situation, thank you :).